# Alamofire HTML request works only once per application install

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I need to make some HTML requests, and I decided to use Alamofire.

For the very first time I make the request below, it works fine, returns me the access key. Then if I try to make any call again (login, logout, register etc. any call), it does not work, it fail and gives me error.

It work fine once again for one time if I remove the application and reinstall it, than I can make 1 request again until it starts to give me errors.

Here is the login request:

```
    let parameters : [ String : String] = [
        "email": email,
        "password":password
    ]
    Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: parameters).validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                if let json = response.result.value {
                    print("JSON: \(json)")
                }
            case .Failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

Here is the error that appears every time after it works for one time per install:

> Error Domain=com.alamofire.error Code=-6003 "Response status code was >unacceptable: 403" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Response status >code was unacceptable: 403}

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Sadly, doesn't work, same error continues

Comment: Hello , try to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Anywhere where the **Result** is available, the **NSHTTPURLResponse** is also provided. Therefore, if you are not passing the **response** around where you may need it, that is an implementation problem on the client side, not an issue with Alamofire. This is exactly why it was designed the way it was.

There are MANY other things in the **response** that may be useful besides the statusCode. Therefore we don't want to make a special exception to the **statusCode**. Here's a quick example of how you should attempt to handle this issue.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get")
    .responseJSON { request, response, result in
        switch result {
        case .Success(let JSON):
            print(JSON)
        case .Failure(let data, let error):
            print(response?.statusCode)
            print(error)

            callFailureMethod(response: response, result: result)
        }
    }
```

OR

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get")
    .responseJSON { request, response, result in
        debugPrint(result)
        print(response?.statusCode)

        callFailureMethod(response: response, result: result)
    }
```

Best of luck!

I'm getting solution from [THIS.](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/664)